# Python + Selenium в .exe

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, pyinstaller

Есть код на python, в котором используется selenium, этот код надо собрать в .exe (использую pyinstaller)
Нашел это - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49853252/create-a-python-executable-with-chromedriver-selenium
написал .spec:

```
# -*- mode: python -*-
block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['main.py'],
             pathex=['F:\\PyCharm Edu 2018.3\\projects\\message_send\\'],
             binaries=[('C:\\Users\\User\\Downloads\\chromedriver.exe','**.\\selenium\\webdriver**')],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='createEVIPOrg_Automation_new',
          debug=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=True )
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               name='**main**')
```

Но pyinstaller выдает ошибку - OSError: [WinError 123] Синтаксическая ошибка в имени файла, имени папки или метке тома: 'F:\PyCharm Edu 2018.3\projects\message_send\dist\**main**'

Возможно он ругается на пробелы в ссылке, попробовал в .spec написать:
' "F:\PyCharm Edu 2018.3\projects\message_send\" '
Ошибка осталась.
Есть идеи как решить?

Comment: name='**main**' А что это?

Comment: Почему там звёздочки?

Comment: Я руководствовался этим ресурсом - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49853252/create-a-python-executable-with-chromedriver-selenium Там указано со звездочками, пробовал без них ошибка осталась